# mock fs failed with jest: " no such file or directory, lstat" , and mock_fs_1.default is not a function

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have a config file that I load with jest and I am trying to use mock-fs library to create a folder for an integration test

I got this error:

```
no such file or directory, lstat : 'path to one of another folder in the current directory '
```

and also I got this :

```
TypeError: mock_fs_1.default is not a function
```

in my config file that I Load to jest, I also bring the following library:

```
import * as getPort from 'get-port';
import { mockServerClient } from 'mockserver-client';
import * as mockServerNode from 'mockserver-node';
import mockfs from 'mock-fs';


 mockfs({
    'path/to/fake/dir': {
      'some-file.txt': 'file content here',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to mocked `fs` which jest is trying to use. You need to `restore` original `fs` after each test

```js
import * as getPort from 'get-port';
import { mockServerClient } from 'mockserver-client';
import * as mockServerNode from 'mockserver-node';
import mockfs from 'mock-fs';

afterEach(() => {
  mockfs.restore();
})

 mockfs({
    'path/to/fake/dir': {
      'some-file.txt': 'file content here',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve a similar issue based on the comments that I saw on [this discussion](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs/issues/234#issuecomment-703740305):

As suggested add this line **before calling the mockfs** function:

```
console = new Console(process.stdout, process.stderr)
```

Of course, restore:

```
afterEach(() => {
    mockFs.restore();
});
```